# How to enable SFTP source connector in Apache kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

i am trying to enable SFTP csv source connector in Apache kafka, before i used the same in the confluent-platform so i am trying to perform the same in Apache variant.

but i cant able to achive the same

Steps i done to enable SFTP csv source connector.

1)Downloaded the kafka-connect-sftp in zip file from the following link.

https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-sftp

2)Extracted the zipped folder and copy the libs folder of kafka-connect-sftp to Apache kafka libs folder under new folder called sftp

3)updated connect-distributor.properties  plugins path like below

**plugin.path=/k_con_test/libs,/k_con_test/libs/sftp**

4)when i try to restart the connect service i am facing so many error in connect console

```
[2021-04-09 14:51:26,305] WARN could not get type for name io.confluent.connect.storage.format.RecordWriterProvider from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name io.confluent.connect.storage.format.RecordWriterProvider
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:312)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:382)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:140)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader$InternalReflections.<init>(DelegatingClassLoader.java:444)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:334)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:268)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:260)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:229)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:206)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:61)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:91)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.confluent.connect.storage.format.RecordWriterProvider
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:310)
        ... 11 more
[2021-04-09 14:51:26,306] WARN could not get type for name io.confluent.connect.storage.format.RecordWriter from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name io.confluent.connect.storage.format.RecordWriter
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:312)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:382)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:140)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader$InternalReflections.<init>(DelegatingClassLoader.java:444)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:334)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:268)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:260)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:229)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:206)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:61)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:91)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.confluent.connect.storage.format.RecordWriter
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:310)
        ... 11 more
[2021-04-09 14:51:26,307] WARN could not get type for name io.confluent.connect.storage.StorageSinkConnectorConfig from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name io.confluent.connect.storage.StorageSinkConnectorConfig
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:312)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:382)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:140)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader$InternalReflections.<init>(DelegatingClassLoader.java:444)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:334)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:268)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:260)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:229)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:206)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:61)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:91)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.confluent.connect.storage.StorageSinkConnectorConfig
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:310)
        ... 11 more
[2021-04-09 14:51:26,310] WARN could not get type for name org.apache.parquet.io.OutputFile from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name org.apache.parquet.io.OutputFile
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:312)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:382)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:140)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader$InternalReflections.<init>(DelegatingClassLoader.java:444)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:334)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:268)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:260)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:229)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:206)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:61)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:91)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.parquet.io.OutputFile
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:310)
        ... 11 more
[2021-04-09 14:51:26,311] WARN could not get type for name org.apache.parquet.io.PositionOutputStream from any class loader (org.reflections.Reflections)
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name org.apache.parquet.io.PositionOutputStream
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:312)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:382)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:140)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader$InternalReflections.<init>(DelegatingClassLoader.java:444)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:334)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:268)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:260)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:229)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:206)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:61)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:91)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.parquet.io.PositionOutputStream
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:310)
        ... 11 more
[2021-04-09 14:51:26,313] ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/confluent/connect/storage/StorageSinkConnectorConfig
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:550)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:96)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3342)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:556)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.versionFor(DelegatingClassLoader.java:395)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.getPluginDesc(DelegatingClassLoader.java:365)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:337)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:268)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:260)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:229)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:206)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.<init>(Plugins.java:61)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.startConnect(ConnectDistributed.java:91)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:78)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.confluent.connect.storage.StorageSinkConnectorConfig
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 24 more
```

cant able to paste the whole log because it is having  very huge number of lines

May i know how to set up these kind of connectors in Apache Kafka

Because i dont think that apache doesn't have specific connector for sftp ,so is it possible to use  confluent connector here?

Comment: Copying things into the libs folder is not correct; you shouldn't modify the Kafka broker classpath. Is there a specific reason not to use `confluent-hub` command given on the site?

Comment: Can you show the content of the stfp folder? You're missing this class, https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-common/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/storage/StorageSinkConnectorConfig.java